# Tomcat giving error with same war file how to solve?

Tags: linux, maven, tomcat, web-applications, deployment

I have deployed a war file of a webapp on linux server. Till yesterday it was working fine. But today when i deployed the war with minor changes it stopped working. 
i am getting this error code.

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Unable to compile class for JSP

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

I have already tried building a clean war and deploying it.
I even tried to deploy the old war which was working but now this is also not working.

Exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:610)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Root Cause

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.io.Writer.<init>(Writer.java:88)
    java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:109)
    java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:148)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Compiler.java:286)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Compiler.java:209)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:534)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:350)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:595)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

welcome.jsp page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Data Build</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${contextPath}/resources/css/style.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/login.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>

<body style="overflow:center">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="heading">Data Build</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form_bg">
                <form>
                    <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="signum" placeholder="Signum" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="align-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default custom-button" onclick="onLogin()">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get this when i again refresh the page.     Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.welcome_jsp

Comment: Show the source code of the `welcome.jsp` page.

Comment: added in the question.